# Cocoa webview garbage collection, crashing when loading

Tags: cocoa, garbage-collection, webview

I have this web view connected via IB in a garbage collected project. I can load a url perfectly fine in the web view one time, but then anytime after that one time it seems to crash randomly. I've got a couple different errors, a few specifically referencing garbage collection and saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS... the most recent and common though is this:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x00007fff8b4ffe90 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000004001ae2c0 in <????> ()
#2  0x00007fff97ab1313 in _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData ()
#3  0x00007fff93e22388 in URLConnectionClient::_clientDidReceiveData(__CFArray const*, URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) ()
#4  0x00007fff93ed3c5b in URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) ()
#5  0x00007fff93dfeb49 in URLConnectionClient::processEvents() ()
#6  0x00007fff93dfe9ee in MultiplexerSource::perform() ()
#7  0x00007fff8fd666e1 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#8  0x00007fff8fd65f4d in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#9  0x00007fff8fd8cd39 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x00007fff8fd8c676 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x00007fff97a54f9f in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] ()
#12 0x00007fff954861a2 in WebCore::ResourceHandle::loadResourceSynchronously(WebCore::NetworkingContext*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::StoredCredentials, WebCore::ResourceError&, WebCore::ResourceResponse&, WTF::Vector<char, 0ul>&) ()
#13 0x00007fff95485c1f in WebCore::FrameLoader::loadResourceSynchronously(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::StoredCredentials, WebCore::ResourceError&, WebCore::ResourceResponse&, WTF::Vector<char, 0ul>&) ()
#14 0x00007fff9548583b in WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::loadRequest(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::SecurityCheckPolicy) ()
#15 0x00007fff95485376 in WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::DocumentThreadableLoader(WebCore::Document*, WebCore::ThreadableLoaderClient*, WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::BlockingBehavior, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::ThreadableLoaderOptions const&, WTF::String const&) ()
#16 0x00007fff95485220 in WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::loadResourceSynchronously(WebCore::Document*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::ThreadableLoaderClient&, WebCore::ThreadableLoaderOptions const&) ()
#17 0x00007fff95485076 in WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::createRequest(int&) ()
#18 0x00007fff95484d07 in WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::send(WTF::String const&, int&) ()
#19 0x00007fff95484807 in WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::send(int&) ()
#20 0x00007fff954844e7 in WebCore::JSXMLHttpRequest::send(JSC::ExecState*) ()
#21 0x00007fff95484432 in WebCore::jsXMLHttpRequestPrototypeFunctionSend(JSC::ExecState*) ()
#22 0x00004f57b12011e8 in <????> ()
#23 0x00007fff900b778b in JSC::Interpreter::execute(JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ScopeChainNode*, JSC::JSObject*) ()
#24 0x000000010c2e4da0 in <????> ()
#25 0x000000010a3f76a0 in <????> ()
#26 0x00007fff90286700 in JSC::JSFunction::~JSFunction() ()
#27 0x4810c08348eba9ab in <????> ()
```

I really don't know what to do. The crashing is sporadic and sometimes I can load the web view a few times before it crashes the app...

Also I've been getting this one a lot:

```
Thread 10, Queue : Garbage Collection Work Queue
#0  0x00007fff90168f6f in auto_fatal ()
#1  0x00007fff9017713b in Auto::Zone::handle_overretained_garbage(void*, int, int) ()
#2  0x00007fff90177844 in Auto::Zone::free_garbage(unsigned long, void**, unsigned long, void**, unsigned long&, unsigned long&) ()
#3  0x00007fff90164837 in auto_collect_internal(Auto::Zone*, unsigned int) ()
#4  0x00007fff9016021a in __auto_zone_collect_block_invoke_0 ()
#5  0x00007fff954098ba in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#6  0x00007fff9540b10a in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#7  0x00007fff9540af66 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#8  0x00007fff9540a760 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#9  0x00007fff91adf3da in _pthread_wqthread ()
#10 0x00007fff91ae0b85 in start_wqthread ()
```